# Traceback (most recent call last): TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, compiler-errors, typeerror, instance, traceback

[Traceback (most recent call last):
File "readability.py", line 11, in 
if (ord(text[i]) > 'a' and ord(text[i]) <= 'z') or (ord(text[i]) > 'A' and ord(text[i]) <= 'Z'):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because one of the items in the condition is of different data type than the other. To convert a str to an int, do `int(str)`. In your code, you should remove `>` from your if statements and do `==` instead (if comparing strings), OR
do `ord(text[i]) >= ord("a")` instead of `ord(text[i]) >= "a"`

Comment: for i in range(counter):
    if (ord(text[i]) > 'a' and ord(text[i]) <= 'z') or (ord(text[i]) > 'A' and ord(text[i]) <= 'Z'):
        letters_count += 1
    elif (ord(text[i]) == ' '):
        word_count += 1
    elif (ord(text[i]) == '.' or ord(text[i]) == '!' or ord(text[i]) == '?'):
        sentence_count += 1
    grade = 0.0588 * (100 * letters_count / word_count) - 0.296 * (100 * sentence_count / word_count) - 15.8
    if (grade < 16 and grade >= 0):
        print(f"Grade {round(grade)} ")

Comment: this is my code can u tell me where I went wrong

Comment: I explained what the problem was in my answer